# Running laravel/lumen in Docker using docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, lumen

I am learning about microservice architecture and I want to setup a simple lumen app to run inside 3 separate containers using `docker-compose`

- **web** - this will run my nginx front server
- **app** - this will run my php-fpm
- **database** - this will run my mysql server

This is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./deploy/web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - app

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./deploy/app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

**deploy/web.dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
ADD deploy/vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**deploy/app.dockerfile**

```
FROM yavin/alpine-php-fpm:7.1
COPY deploy/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/50-setting.ini
COPY deploy/php-fpm.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.conf
```

**deploy/php.ini**

```
max_execution_time=30
max_input_time=60
memory_limit=128M
post_max_size=256M
upload_max_filesize=256M
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors=On
date.timezone=Europe/London
```

**deploy/php-fpm.conf**

```
[www]
user = nobody
group = nobody
listen = [::]:9000
chdir = /var/www
pm = static
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
catch_workers_output = Yes
```

**vhost.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

When I run `docker-compse up` I can see everything is running fine:

[image]

[image]

But when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 I get the `This site can’t be reached` error in chrome.

I am on windows using Docker Toolbox, and my docker version is: `Docker version 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25`

Any ideas how to properly setup LEMP stack on docker to run a simple lumen app?

Comment: Question updated. I realised I had typo in my `php-fpm.conf`, It's been corrected and the containers were re-build and I still can't access my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Toolbox is an older solution for Docker on Windows and Mac. There is no local host proxy from containers (you cannot use `localhost` to get to container exposed ports).

With Docker Toolbox actually comes Docker Machine, which is running a virtual machine behind the scenes and this virtual machine has a IP address. You can get the IP address using:

```
docker-machine ip
```

Or:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

It will give you something like 192.168.88.100. You would then use this address to get to your exposed ports such as http://192.168.88.100:8080/.

Alternatively, you could remove the Docker Machine using `docker-machine rm`, uninstall Docker Toolbox, and then install Docker for Windows instead which will allow you to access published container ports on `localhost`.